# Rewrite root directory and index.php to custom URL in browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using XAMPP 7.2.6 on Windows and my root web folder is htdocs. I have the mod_rewrite module installed in Apache.

I have a website project in `C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz`

I want to use mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL of the root directory and index.php to a custom URL in the browser - `index.php?action=viewFrontPage&pageId=2`

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/index.php? /index.php?action=viewFrontPage&pageId=2
```

This does nothing and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your approach, but I will point out the first and most obvious:

Your current configuration

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php? /index.php?action=viewFrontPage&pageId=2
```

does not express what you expect it to express and in fact that rule will *never* get applied. Why? Check the documentation! That is where you can read that the pattern will get matched against a *relative* path of a rewriting rule is implemented in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"). You try to match an *absolute* path.

That is why I would suggest this as a first step towards your goal (which is actually unclear from your question):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /index.php?action=viewFrontPage&pageId=2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

That adapted rule will *not* work. This brings us to step 2... The issue you now face is that you have created an endless rewriting loop. You redirect `/index.php` to `/index.php`... not a good idea for obvious reasons. So you need to prevent such a loop, but for that you will need to be able to tell *how* the server should distinguish between the two situation. Are you able to?

This might be a start, but you will certainly need to adapt it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=viewFrontPage&pageId=2$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /index.php?action=viewFrontPage&pageId=2 [END]
```

Also also you wrote that you want to rewrite the "root directory", but it is unclear what you actually mean by that...

Comment: Thanks arkascha, this help me a lot!